# Tableau Extensions, Writing custom Extensions to Download Data Across multiple sheets

Tags: tableau-api

Has anyone used a tableau extension to download data from the dashboards in a very precise manner? I am looking to upgrade the download functionality by building a custom download button that produce specific reports based on the sheets.

The goal would be a download button that can write the information back to the server and allow the user to download that file (something palpable for end users like excel).

I am aware of tableau servers existing download to excel functionality, but do to permission for the end user we cannot enable this, and the complexity of the dashboards makes it less useful regardless.

If anyone has any links or info on this please share, thanks.

Comment: Unless you are looking for a paid subscription (it has to be hosted somewhere), you will have to build/host the extension internally. For a list of all Tableau extensions check out the gallery - https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/

Comment: There are no download specific extensions in the gallery. Your best bet would be to create and host in house. Here is the tutorial to get started - https://github.com/tableau/extensions-api/tree/master/Tutorial